# Apple script that can scan a pdf document and copy all the annotated highlighted text to clipboard with a page reference

Tags: pdf, applet, applescript, automator

When doing research I find myself usually annotating a pdf document (highlighting, adding notes), then I will create a note in Evernote and index all my annotations.

For example,

---

p 3 - "is it possible for schools to change their practices and thereby have a strongly positive effect on student achievement?"

p 10 - "the district boldly moved forward with several new reforms"

---

My hope is to work with a pdf document, annotate it, then run the applet which would copy all my annotations (highlights and notes) to clipboard, where then I could paste them in a note, thereby having an index of all the points I found useful.

I am using a mac, and am open to using which ever language would be simple to creating this. My thoughts are that an applescript would be best.

Comment: Give Skim a try, as Lauri Ranta suggests. You won't regret it.

Answer (score 2):

[Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net) can export notes as text, and it also has an AppleScript dictionary.

`tell application "Skim" to tell document 1 to save as "notes as text" in "/Users/username/Desktop/notes.txt"`

The output looks like this:

```
* Highlight, page 1
ocument (highlighting

* Text Note, page 1
aa

* Highlight, page 1
ent, annotate it,
```